# Seta para mover para a direita da página não para no final

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde,

Estou precisando de uma ajuda pois construí uma página horizontal que além do scroll do mouse ela também usa as setas na lateral para a movimentação, mas quanto mais você aperta as setas, mais ela avança independente se chegou ao final da página ou não, envio o código que eu usei, será que poderiam me dar uma ajuda:

```
var projObj = null;

function init(){
   projObj = document.getElementById('PagProjetos');
   projObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
   projObj.style.right = '0px';
}

function moveRight(){
   projObj.style.right = parseInt(projObj.style.right) + 600 + 'px';

}
function stop(){
   projObj.style.right = '0px'; 
}

window.onload =init;
```

Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Fiz umas pesquisas e consegui chegar ao código abaixo, mas mesmo assim não funcionou, será que alguém poderia dar um help?

```
<script>
```

```
function init(){
   projObj = document.getElementById('PagProjetos');
   projObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
   projObj.style.right = '0px';

  totalDeImagens = document.getElementeByName('nomeDasImagens');
}

function moveRight(){

  if(contadorDeImages< totalDeImagens){
    projObj.style.right = parseInt(projObj.style.right) + 600 + 'px';
    contadorDeImages++;
  }else{
    projObj.style.right = '0px';
    contadorDeImages = 0;
  }
}
function stop(){
   projObj.style.right = '0px'; 
}

window.onload =init;
```

//-->